# Measuring request latency while using persistent connections

Tags: netty

I want to measure individual request latency. I created a handler overriding channelOpen and channelClosed. This seemed to work fine but behind a load balancer I started seeing many multi-second latencies. I suspect this is due to persistent connections and I'm measure the total socket time.

After reading the Channel docs again I think I should be overriding channelConnected/Disconnected instead. I'm unable to reproduce the long latencies locally so I'm asking for a little clarity here.

Comment: I now think overriding messageReceived/writeComplete will provide the most accurate numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes... messageReceived and writeComplete is the way to g